# Connection to SQLServer2012 with JTDS driver and Windows authentication

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQLServer 2012 through Java. I have tried using the Microsoft supplied jdbc driver, as well as the jtds driver.

However, whenever i try to load either of the drivers,  I get a "No suitable driver found" exception.

The connection URL i have is:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/mineDB;instance=SQLServer2012;integratedSecurity=true;USENTLMV2=true
```

The driver class name:

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I have loaded the jtds.1.3.1.jar file into my classpath system variable, and when trying to use the windows jdbc driver i did the same

EDIT:

Forgot to mention. the driver is called using Class.forName().

Everything is being done on one machine at the moment, and once it is all working i'm going to see if i can get an external database connection working

Comment: The connecting java program is it a standalone program or is it running in an app server?

Comment: Most ways of running java applications ignore the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Also, I am not sure if jTDS has support for JDBC 4 type driver auto-loading, so you may need to load it explicitly with `Class.forName`.